# how to get PayPal client ID

Tags: ios, paypal

I am developing an iphone app, i want to integrate it with PayPal which will use rest API.

I downloaded SDK 1.0.4 for iOS from this.
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

There is a sample code given by PayPal.
But in this app i need to change PayPal client id and email address.

define kPayPalClientId @"YOUR CLIENT ID HERE"
define kPayPalReceiverEmail @"YOUR_PAYPAL_EMAIL@yourdomain.com"

how to get PayPal client id?
and how can i test it if money is transfered or not with the single PayPal account?

Comment: how you go these keys?define kPayPalClientId @"YOUR CLIENT ID HERE"
define kPayPalReceiverEmail @"YOUR_PAYPAL_EMAIL@yourdomain.com"

Comment: you need to give your app's client id which you can get from link given in answer and specify email address of the receiver.

Comment: i have done it successfully as it shows proof of transaction (nslogs dictionary) . what i need to know is, how to verify this transaction so i can see money flowing between both accounts on Paypal(sandbox)  ??how to verify mobile payments? documentation is confusing me

Comment: Even i m bit confused about verification of transaction. But i m quite sure that you don't need to verify transaction to see effect on Paypal(sandbox) account.

Comment: thats alright if you are confused. now see, i am getting success message by paypal but amount is not transferring through two accounts

Comment: make sure you are giving right email address of the other PayPal(sandbox) account.

Comment: yeah m giving right email address. please tell me, if buyer account doesn't have money in it, is it possible to buy gods on sandbox environment?

Comment: yeah it works in sandbox mode even if buyer account doesn't have money in it. Even i posted question asking for this but didn't get gud ans.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can obtain your PayPal API credentials, including Client ID, by visiting the [Applications page on the PayPal Developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications) and logging in with your PayPal account.

Once logged in on this page, you will be assigned a **sandbox** Client ID, which will let you test your iOS integration against the PayPal sandbox. In your code, set the receiver email to a business sandbox account email address, then use a personal sandbox account email and password to log in to PayPal in the UI of your app. You can create business and personal sandbox accounts on the [Sandbox accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts) page.

To obtain your **live** Client ID, you will need to have a business account. If you don't yet have a business account, there is a link at the bottom of that same Applications page that will get you started. For live transactions, use your PayPal email address as the receiver email.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to https://developer.paypal.com and click the Applications tab.

On the https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps click Create App.

On the Create New App page, provide an app name.

Click Create App, and then review the information displayed about your app (as described below)

now you will get client id